# SVN Latest Head revision: Branch or Trunk

Tags: svn, head

I understand that HEAD is the latest(youngest) revision in the repository. But also that main trunk and all individual branches have their own HEAD.

So, if i create a branch and make several commits on it, would the HEAD revision of branch be greater that HEAD revision of trunk. In this case, when another user gets a HEAD revision, would he end up getting the latest revision from my branch instead of trunk.

Answer (score 0):

No. Each branch (or the trunk) has a unique pointer to its own head. They don't overlap. When you do a get latest you get it for the checkout you are working on.